# Can i invoke this.method within constructor function

Tags: javascript

Im trying to invoke method inside constructor, is it not possible or have i missed something?

```
function Rectangle(height, width) {
  this.height = height;
  this.width = width;
  this.calcArea = function() {
    console.log(this.height);
    return this.height * this.width;
  };
  this.calcArea(); // trying to do it here, its invoked but no result  
 }
var newone = new Rectangle(12,24);
```

Comment: It's working just fine, but what do you expect should happen with the returned result from `calcArea()` ?

Comment: kinda hoped for newone.calcArea would be result of 12*24

Comment: `console.log(this.calcArea())` update to this.

Comment: `calcArea` is a fuction. If you want a value, try using IIFE.

Comment: That's not how it works, why would you suddenly have a property holding the value from the function, without ever creating such a property

Comment: See this -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/10sn22fq/

Comment: ok, thank you, got it, again missed basic stuff

Comment: I think you have successfully confused functions with classes(like in JAVA). You want a Rectangle class with area calculating function and save this to its private `area` variable whenever its instance is created , i.e call in its constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```js
function Rectangle(height, width) {
  var self = this;
  self.height = height;
  self.width = width;
  self.calcArea = (function() {
    console.log(this.height);
    return self.height * self.width;
  })();
 }
var newone = new Rectangle(12,24)
console.log(newone.calcArea);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working just fine. You are not using the returned value.

```
function Rectangle(height, width) {
  this.height = height;
  this.width = width;
  this.calcArea = function() {
    console.log(this.height);
    return this.height * this.width;
  };
  var area =this.calcArea(); // trying to do it here, its invoked but no result  
  console.log(area); //288
 }
var newone = new Rectangle(12,24);
```